# i18n with easy_localization in flutter

Tags: flutter, internationalization

The latest version of easy_localization package is very different than any tutorial or article online.

I struggled a bit with the new version but i got stuck when i tried to create a button to change language dynamically. The old way was data = EasyLocalizationProvider.of(context).data, and i insert data.changeLocale(Locale(ar-SA)); inside onPressed function, that's it. But i can't find the changeLocale function, nor the EasyLocalizationProvider class.

How can i implement this using the latest version?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer... i inserted this inside the onPressed of the button "context.locale = Locale('ar', 'SA');" and it changed the language of the app...

Comment: I am curious about this: can easy_localization support an English folder with multiple JSON files to be used for the language? The idea would be that you have a folder for each language with multiple jsons in it that are all used together for a particular language instead of one big json file for the language.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried before.. sorry I couldn't be of any help...

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
context.locale = Locale('ar', 'SA');
```

or:

```
EasyLocalization.of(context).locale = Locale('ar', 'SA');
```

Comment: thank you for your response... but i tried both of your solutions inside a button but this exception was thrown "'package:easy_localization/src/easy_localization_app.dart': Failed assertion: line 274 pos 14: 'parent.supportedLocales.contains(locale)': is not true."

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I copied your questions's locale without testing. If it is correct now, you can mark it as 'approved' rather than putting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to add language to supportedLocales as done in main  supportedLocales:

```
[Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('tr', 'TR'), Locale("ar")],
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I made silly mistake

I assign

```
final locale = Locale("en-US");
context.setLocale(locale);
```

instead of

```
final locale = Locale("en", "US");
context.setLocale(locale);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i used:

```
                context.setLocale(const Locale('uk'));
```

and got an error: "parent.supportedLocales.contains(locale)': is not true."
so i used this:

```
                context.setLocale(const Locale('uk', ''));
```